# Multiple @Scheduled annotations at one method

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Is it allowed / working to have multiple @Scheduled annotations at one method?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 0 * * *", zone = "Europe/Stockholm")
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000 * 60 * 20, initialDelay = 1000 * 60 * 5)
public void setSalariesAsArchived() {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly legal as `@Scheduled` is a `@Repeatable` annotation like stated in [the Javadoc for `@Schedules`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Schedules.html)

> Container annotation that aggregates several `Scheduled` annotations.
> Can be used natively, declaring several nested `Scheduled` annotations. Can also be used in conjunction with Java 8's support for repeatable annotations, where `Scheduled` can simply be declared several times on the same method, implicitly generating this container annotation.

So you can either use it as you did, or use `@Schedules` to wrap it like in the following example

```
@Schedules({
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 5 0 * * *", zone = "Europe/Stockholm"),
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000 * 60 * 20, initialDelay = 1000 * 60 * 5)
})
public void setSalariesAsArchived() {
//...
}
```